# Running specific npm scripts upon Firebase deployment in Github Workflows

Tags: firebase, github-actions, npm-scripts

I have a deployment to Firebase projects (one for test env, one for production) through Github Workflow actions. When the target branch where is pushed is main it should build with the staging build script running vite in staging mode, after that it should deploy on the firebase test env project using the `npm run start:staging` script. How do I specify what start script Firebase needs to use when deploying?

```
- name: Build Application
        run: |
          if [ "$GITHUB_REF" == "refs/heads/main" ]; then
            npm run build:staging # Use staging build on main for development environment
          elif [ "$GITHUB_REF" == "refs/heads/production" ]; then
            npm run build    # Use regular build for production environment
          fi

      - name: Deploy to Firebase Test build
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
        uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TEST }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: my-app-test

      - name: Deploy to Firebase Production build
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/production'
        uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRODUCTION }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: myapp-prod
```

I tried adding args to the deployment but it doesn't allow that. Also tried rewrites in Firebase hosting but it did not seem to be able to do that as well.